# Is Amazon a sponsor of Ubuntu development?

Tags: canonical, amazon

When I installed Ubuntu, the launcher included these icons:

- Search your computer and online sources
- Files
- Firefox
- LibreOffice Writer
- LibreOffice Calc
- LibreOffice Impress
- Ubuntu Software Center
- Amazon
- [size] Volume
- Trash

(I'm not sure of the icons' official names, so I'm going by the mouse-over text. The Volume icon points to the NTFS volume on my machine, which is installed dual-boot.)

The odd one out in the list is "Amazon". I know that Canonical leads development of Ubuntu, and I am aware of the controversy about sending search results to Amazon by default (in an earlier version). I know Amazon offers Ubuntu installations on their cloud servers. But how did Amazon get an icon on the launcher? Did they pay Canonical money? Did they pay by donating a substantial amount of development to Ubuntu? Is it a left-over element of the deal that sent them search results? Some combination of those? Or something that no one knows except lawyers for Canonical and Amazon?

I did some web searching and found that there was an agreement to give Amazon the icon placement, but nothing about the terms of the deal. But the articles I found didn't say whether the terms were undisclosed, or if the terms are public but not just mentioned in the articles.

Comment: Note: I checked the askubuntu tour to see whether this falls into the scope of appropriate questions. It's not in the "ask about" section, but it's also not in the "don't ask about" section; a question about the business side of Ubuntu seems to fall within the domain of the Ubuntu community.

Comment: AFAIK, Amazon is not a sponsor of Canonical/Ubuntu.  I did at one point suggest that setting the referrer link on Amazon purchase queries might be a viable source of revenue in chat.  I consider myself not that retarded, and I would think that other at least not that retarded people could also consider it a revenue stream.  In that respect, it would seem a decent way to raise money.